Which one is more in the system with the following features? Electrical energy produced or energy consumed
Can a stable energy system be created using variable capacitors to generate high current for energy recovery?
Based on my previous question, I proposed this new question in a more complete form
My idea is:
If two charged capacitors are connected in parallel so that their positive plates are connected together and their negative plates are connected together. Then, if the capacity of one of them changes, a significant current is created in the circuit. If we put a consumer (such as a lamp) in the path of this current, this energy can be used to turn on the lamp.
changing the capacity of one of the capacitors must be done continuously and current must be maintained in the circuit By doing this alternately, it can be seen that the current in the circuit is established, but its direction changes alternately. But the total electric charge difference of two capacitors is constant. That is, if we apply the same initial capacity to the capacitor whose capacity we have continuously changed, we will see that the total energy in the two capacitors has not changed in the ratio of the first state.
My question is:
• Can the energy produced in this circuit be enough to compensate for the energy lost (for example, heat due to the change of capacitor capacity)?
• If we can compensate for the energy loss, can such a system be used as a sustainable energy source?
3.This assembly consumes mechanical energy to change the capacitance of the capacitor. and produces electrical energy. If possible, specify with a theoretical or experimental example that the mechanical energy consumed is greater or the electrical energy produced
I am looking to understand what is the power dissipation in variable capacitors and whether this idea is practically or theoretically feasible. Any theoretical or practical views on this matter would be very helpful.
Here I gave a theoretical example using a virtual laboratory
111 We charged two capacitors with batteries. Now the electric potential difference of each of them is equal to 100 volts. Then we made this electric circuit using light bulbs and switches.]1
222-We double the capacity of one of the capacitors. As a result, its electric potential difference is equal to 50 volts. We close the key. Then the electric current is established in the circuit. And the lamp turns on.]2
333-After some time, the electric potential difference of the two capacitors becomes equal. And the electric current in the circuit stops.]3
444= We change the capacity of the capacitor again and its electric potential difference changes. As a result, electric current is established in the circuit. And the lamp turns on.]4
555-After some time, the electric potential difference between the two capacitors is equal again and the electric current in the circuit is cut off.]5
666=We change the capacity of the capacitor and the capacity of the capacitor is equal to the initial state. Again, the electric current is established in the circuit and the lamp turns on.]6
777=After some time, the electric current in the circuit stops. Compared to the first case, the electric potential difference of the two capacitors has not changed. Because the electric charge in the circuit has been stable.]7
Test description: This test has seven stages. At the end of the test, the capacitors have not changed compared to the first stage. Of course, this is a simple test and does not take into account the energy loss in the capacitors. The important point is how much the energy loss in the capacitor is normally. If the value is small, the system or the circuit is good. If it is too much, this system is not good. With a detailed example, the energy consumed in this circuit should be compared with the energy produced
If possible, guide me with a theoretical or theoretical example and compare the energy consumption and production of this circuit
In this electric circuit, the total electric charge difference remains constant in every state

This question is similar to: Can a stable energy system be created using variable capacitors to generate high current for energy recovery?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"Can the energy produced in this circuit be enough to compensate for the energy lost (for example, heat due to the change of capacitor capacity)?" - "If we can compensate for the energy loss, can such a system be used as a sustainable energy source?" - these questions have both been repeatedly answered in the negative. You always lose more energy out of this interaction than what you gain. "Compensating for the energy loss" is just hooking the thing up to a battery, at which point you should just hook the load up to that battery instead of all this capacitor stuff.

@controlgroup, Re, "You always lose more energy out of this interaction than what you gain." IMO, that is a very misleading statement. It might lead somebody to believe that the apparatus can somehow gain energy. When people say "gain energy" they often are talking about creating energy from nothing. When they say "loss," on the other hand, they often mean, "converted to heat." So, are we talking about a machine that makes heat from nothing? If not, then what do you mean by "gain?" What do you mean by "loss?"

@iii_Amirܜܛܜܛܜ  Your original question still is open. This new question essentially is the same. If you feel that the original does not adequately express what you are trying to ask, then please feel free to edit the original instead of continually posting new versions of it every time you feel the need for improvement.

@SolomonSlow That’s fair; I mean to say that the power produced by this process (and there does seem to be power produced if you were to try this) integrated over time would be less than the energy that you have to put into the capacitors/changing capacitances; that is, the net amount of energy in the system doesn’t change/decreases.

@controlgroup, Yes. If this apparatus is proposed as an alternative to a conventional, electromagnetic generator, then it would be completely impractical. But if OP thinks it is a "free energy" machine, then they might not care so much about efficiency. Even the tiniest fraction of "free energy" still would be "free." And, if you had unlimited time and financial and material resources, then you could always scale the thing up until the "tiny" fraction was enough to meet your needs.
